# Tsql - Pivot data for every 2 records

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

DATA

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE([Group] int,GroupOrder   int,Response int)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1,1,1)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1,2,1)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2,1,1)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2,2,1)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2,3,2)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2,4,1)

Group GroupOrder    Response
1     1           1
1     2           1
2     1           1
2     2           1
2     3           2
2     4           1
```

Regarding the above data, the Group defines the Group by logic which means I have data for 2 groupIds i.e. 1 and 2 The response is what I need pivoted in such a fashion that the first value of the response goes to the first column and the second value goes to the second column per group and as defined by the group order, the expected result is :

```
Group  Response Newcol
1         1        1
2         1        1
2         2        1
```

The first value of Response should go to Response Column and the next value should go to Newcol moving onto the next record for that group (If exists) the same logic should keep on following.

I have tried ROW_NUMBER() and Pivot but I haven't been successful.

Comment: are there always going to be pairs? Like could group 3 have 1 row?

Comment: A pair will always exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE([Group] int,GroupOrder   int,Response int)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1,1,1)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1,2,1)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2,1,1)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2,2,1)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2,3,2)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2,4,1)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (3,1,5)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (4,1,2)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (4,2,1)



select [Group], [1] as Response , [0] as NewCol 
from 
(
    select t.[group], 
            response, 
            GroupOrder%2 as pivotcol, 
            case when round(cast(grouporder as float)/2,0) <> cast(grouporder as float)/2 
                 then grouporder 
                 else grouporder-1 
            end as GG
    from @temp t
) dat
pivot(max(response) for pivotcol in ([1],[0])) pvt
order by [group]
```

Results:

```
Group       Response    NewCol
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1
2           1           1
2           2           1
3           5           NULL
4           2           1
```